# Add custom title and custom alternative text to Logo Image Settings

Tags: forms

I am looking for a module that adds custom Title and Alt fields to the box shown below in the Appearance Settings of a theme

[image]

Comment: Title and alt fields of what?  The whole site? are you sure you're not looking for `admin/config/system/site-information`?

Comment: @Darvanen I am looking for a module that adds custom Title and Alt fields to box shown above (the box shows some Drupal Logo Image Settings) in the Appearance Settings of a theme and no, i had a look into admin/config/system/site-information and there was nothing near to what i clearly need. thanks

Comment: Manikaprasanth is on the right track.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can alter theme form using, `form_system_theme_settings_alter` in `theme-settings.php`

```
function test_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id = NULL)  {

$form['logo']['settings']['alt_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Alt Text'),
    '#description' => t("Alt text")
  );
$form['logo']['settings']['title_text'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Title Text'),
    '#description' => t("Title")
  );

}
```

You can get this value `theme_get_setting('title_text')` in `page.tpl.php`,and i haven't tried this. Check from your side, let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: no issues, works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

I think this functionality you seek will be found on themes and not in a module. The designer of the theme will decide to add such functionality at the theme level. You could add this to your own theme or sub-theme if you wish as well. Here is a link to [Creating advanced theme settings](https://www.drupal.org/node/177868)

Alternatively, as it is a once-off site-specific setting, just add it to your theme's page.tpl.php file. This is from Bartik's page.tpl.php file

```
<?php if ($logo): ?>
  <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home" id="logo">
    <img src="<?php print $logo; ?>" alt="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" />
  </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```